# How to access controls?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have just created a window, containing a fill-in field (`TestField`) and a checkbox (`chk_TestField`):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE TestField AS INTEGER VIEW-AS FILL-IN.
DEFINE VARIABLE chk_TestField AS LOGICAL VIEW_AS TOGGLE-BOX.
```

It is very simple to change the value of the fill-in field, based on the checking of the checkbox, something like:

```
ON VALUE-CHANGED OF chk_TestField IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
DO:
  TestField = 5.
END.
```

However, I'm interested in changing an attribute of the Fill-in field itself, not the integer it represents (I would like to make the fill-in field read-only), how to I do this?

I've tried:

```
ON VALUE-CHANGED OF chk_TestField IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
DO:
  TestField.Read-Only = NOT(chk_TestField).
END.
```

This, obviously, does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ASSIGN TestField:READ-ONLY IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = TRUE.
```

or

```
ASSIGN Table.TestField:READ-ONLY IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = TRUE.
```

Comment: In other words: instead of a dot, I should have put a semi-colon :-)

Comment: ... and in top of that: my initial idea that variables and their controls are separated in some way is wrong: the controls are accessible directly via the variables they represent.

Comment: A semicolon is ; a colon is :